# gevent/threading causes some deadlock

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock, gevent

I have this code, whose purpose is to dedupe requests.

```
def dedup_requests(f):
    pending = {}

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        key = _make_call_key(args, kwargs)
        if key not in pending:
            pending[key] = gevent.spawn(f, *args, **kwargs)
        result = pending[key].get()
        if key in pending:
            del pending[key]
        return result

    return wrapped
```

I suspect it is causing a deadlock somehow (this happens once in awhile, and I can't reproduce it).

It happens both when using threading and gevent.

Is the recurring use of `get` allowed?

Can this code even produce a deadlock when threading is not involved?

Note that it runs under other gevent tasks, so spawned tasks might spawn additional tasks, in case that's an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I still don't exactly understand the source of the deadlock (my best guess is that `get` doesn't really work as expected when called more than once), this seems to work:

```
from gevent import lock

def queue_identical_calls(f, max_size=100):
    pending = {}

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        key = _make_call_key(args, kwargs)
        if key not in pending:
            pending[key] = lock.BoundedSemaphore(1)
        lock_for_current_call = pending[key]
        lock_for_current_call.acquire()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        lock_for_current_call.release()

        if len(pending) > max_size:
            pending.clear()

        return result

    return wrapped
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that your code is not async.  You need to have the function itself handle the key update and then in a while loop test for your values.  This is an example of async working.  You can prove it by noticing that the last element sometimes shows up first in the list.

```
import gevent
import random

pending = {}
def dedup_requests(key, *args, **kwargs):
    global pending
    if key not in pending:
        gevent.spawn(ftest, key, *args, **kwargs)

def ftest(key, *args, **kwargs):
    global pending
    z = random.randint(1,7)
    gevent.sleep(z)
    pending[key] = z
    return z

l = ['test','test2','test3']
for i in l:
    dedup_requests(i)

while 1:
    if set(pending.keys()) != set(l):
        print(pending)
    else:
        print(pending)
        break
    gevent.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to address the same issue. The point is to block identical work that was asked by many "threads" at the same time (imagine calling with the same string a lot of times, at the same second). In your solution the sleep (which simulates networking I assume) will happen many times. Your solution is essentially memorization.

Comment: The set function dedupes for you.

Comment: Sleep allows the application to move through the greenlets, `sleep(0)` will allow you to move through in real time.

Comment: IIUC the `set` doesn't dedupe early enough, nor the use of dictionary.

To better understand what I mean, add a line in `f_test` that represents a network request, (e.g. `remote_procedure_call()`), by following the code you'll see that this line would be called per element in `l`, regardless of duplication.

Comment: I just provided and example of ASYNC.  in ftest you would check the key before running your function, if the key existed you would cancel.  I think your answer below destroys the async process and turns it back into a single threaded blocking process.

Comment: The point is not to parallelize calls. The point is to prevent identical calls coming in from different threads.

Comment: Consider two threads, A and B. The two are making requests to a server C.
As long as A and B are making different requests, it makes sense to send them all in parallel to C. But if some of the requests that A and B are sending are identical, and C is a pure function, then a obvious optimization would be to send these requests only once. This is like caching just before the request came back.

So again, the point is not parallelization. The point is waiting on the *same* request from different threads.

Comment: But... GEVENT is not parallelization.  It is cooperative, meaning once it receives a request and sends it off on an IO bound request it can take more requests while waiting.  The dictionary however will ONLY be accessed sequentially.  So once a dictionary key is created, another duplicate job WILL be detected and ignored.  Their will never be an instance where the dict will be written to at the exact same time, thus weeding out dupes.

Comment: Nonetheless, two requests will leave your machine (the second will leave while the first is pending), and two requests will arrive to the other machine, making it bear unwanted load. You're welcome to try it yourself.